# Fonts: achieving a clean look of the math

Tags: fonts

With `dsfonts`, the square roots don't have the thick bold top bar on some of the symbols as with `pxfonts`, but with `pxfonts`, the `\int` and the other forms `\iint` all appear vertical whereas with only `dsfonts` `\int` in angled.

Is there a way to achieve the square root look of `dsfonts` and the treatment of `\int` of `pxfonts`?

`dsfonts` alone: (notice the integrals but the square roots is cleaner)

[image]

`pxfonts` alone which also causes errors: (notice the square root but the integrals match)

[image]

**both fonts:**

[image]

Comment: I do not get the thicker square-root line when using `pxfonts`.  Did you do something with other packages to make the division line thinner?  Are your versions up to date?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes well as you can see, I do.

Comment: @dustin --- It could be a viewer issue. Try zooming in, or printing out a page.

Comment: @IanThompson it could be but I am sceptical since it only happens to one font class.  I like the look of the solution I found online so I think I am going to stick with it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a lot of searching I found this set up.  The only problem is I will have to go through all the pages looking for overlap.

[image]

```
% Euler for math | Palatino for rm | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt               
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl} % rm                                                  
\linespread{1.05}        % Palatino needs more leading                               
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss                                                     
\usepackage{courier} % tt                                                            
%\usepackage{euler} % math                                                           
\usepackage{eulervm}
% a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)                        
\normalfont
```