# \sqrt symbol with a vertical part

Tags: math-mode, symbols

It seems that for a given height, the \sqrt symbol "switches" it's type, and it becomes vertical at some part, like here:

[image]

But I want it to be like the second one. What is the solution for this?

EDIT: I've cut this line out of my .tex file. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{enumerate}          
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{enumerate}[1.]

        \item[\textbf{MO:}] {}  

             \begin{enumerate}[a)]

             \item{
             $$\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}
             \sqrt{\frac{1+(-1)^k}{3+\dfrac{1}{k^2}+\dfrac{8}{k^3}}}=
             \sqrt{\dfrac{1+1}{3+0+0}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$$}

             \end{enumerate}

        \end{enumerate}

        \end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've done it, hope it gives enough information about it.

Comment: the computer modern font (the default font with (la)tex) has several sizes of radical signs, but after a certain point, it can't enlarge them any more, and instead uses the version with a vertical part that can be extended ad infinitum with vertical line segments.  you've exceeded the size limit.

Comment: Your code, as it is, is not compilable. Please load the required packages. Also, refrain from using `$$` for delimiting display math; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to for more detail.

Comment: I had a similar issue with square roots and this same problem.  By changing fonts, I was able to get rid of it. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119176/fonts-achieving-a-clean-look-of-the-math/119181#119181

Comment: Also, some PDF viewers create artefacts that look like this. Does the problem persist if you change the zoom?

Comment: Yes, it remains the same even if I zoom in or out.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Then there's no possibility to extend it's limit without changing the font?

Comment: Unrelated note: `\item` does not take a mandatory argument, so you do not have to write `\item{item text}`, it is sufficient with `\item item text`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED to provide second cut (with optional argument for fine-tuning the vertical height of the scaled root symbol).  What I do here is take a standard size sqrt sign and stretch it vertically to match the height of its argument, using the `scalerel` package.  The fine-tuning of the height is done with the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\mysqrt[2][0pt]{\stretchrel{\sqrt{}}{\addstackgap%
  [#1]{$\displaystyle\overline{#2}$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}
             \mysqrt[1pt]{\frac{1+(-1)^k}{3+\dfrac{1}{k^2}+\dfrac{8}{k^3}}}=
             \sqrt{\dfrac{1+1}{3+0+0}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}
\]
\[
\mysqrt[.4pt]{\frac{\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{a}{b}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also seems to be a solution for my integral notation problems, as you generally provided a solution! Thank you!

Comment: @Sphery  Glad to help.  Note that `\stretchrel` can take an optional argument that specifies the minimum aspect ratio (in %), so that if the vertical stretch is too large, horizontal expansion occurs.  Thus, `\stretchrel[400]{...}` limits the stretched aspect ratio of the root sign to 4.00

Comment: @Sphery Please see revised answer.